# Modifying existing regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the existing regex:

```
self.metadata = re.sub('(?<=<file_name>)\d{4,}','', self.metadata)
```

This will do the following conversion:

```
<file_name>1232434_FILE.mov --> <file_name>FILE.mov
```

However, I do not want it to strip a filename if there is a `.` (period) directly after it.

So, the result should be:

```
<file_name>1232434_FILE.mov --> <file_name>FILE.mov
<file_name>123445.mov --> <file_name>123445.mov
```

What would be the new correct regular expression to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a lookahead :

```
self.metadata = re.sub('(?<=<file_name>)\d{4,}(?![.\d])','', self.metadata)
```

```
<file_name>1232434_FILE.mov => <file_name>_FILE.mov
<file_name>1232434FILE.mov  => <file_name>FILE.mov
<file_name>123445.mov       => <file_name>123445.mov
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fOub_KNXb4EPpqNc)

Comment: Lol, I guess a negative lookahead makes more sense than a lookahead with a negatiave character class +1

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookahead to assert that your file name is followed by a non-digit, non `.` character.  Note, we can't just look for a non `.` character, because that could be your 5th digit (since we match 4+ digits).

```
self.metadata = re.sub('(?<=<file_name>)\d{4,}(?=[^\d.])','', self.metadata)
```

[**RegEx**](http://regex101.com/r/zW9yS7)

```
(?<=<file_name>)\d{4,}(?=[^\d.])
```

Note, this will replace `<file_name>1232434_FILE.mov` to `<file_name>_FILE.mov` but your current solution does that as well..